# Border-radius issue on iPad, iPad 2

Tags: ios, css, ipad

Having border-radius issues on iPad(3.2), iPad 2 (4.3.2).

Here's the code:

```
.articles .post .left img{
   width:100%; 
   border-radius: 0 0 100% 0; 
   -moz-border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
   -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
   -webkit-transition: border-radius 1s;
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
   transition-duration: 0.5s;
   transition-property: all;
   transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get the desired result I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
```

As Safari on IOS5 needs that to render border radius.

Comment: Tried that, but it's not having any effect on iPad or iPad 2.

Comment: Is it working on other versions of IOS, other iPads?, can you post the Html and CSS for the page as a codepen so we can better debug

Comment: Okay, I checked it on iPad 2 (5.0) and it's working. But when viewing it on iPad 2 (4.3.2) the effect does not show. Could this mean border-radius is not supported below iOS v 5.0?

Comment: I don't think IOS4 supports a percentage as border radius

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 4, use border-radius css on the container of img and set over-flow:hidden.
the container will 'cut' the img into rounded cornor.

its a tweak.